# get a function of another controller angularjs

Tags: angularjs, controller

I have a table that contains the product listing with the respective controller. From this table I open a modal to include a product that uses another controller. The issue is that when saving a record, I need to update the table using a method that is in the list controller. I found some solutions but none worked. Does anyone have a workable solution?

controller of my list

```
app.controller("listaProdutoController", function ($scope, $http, $q,usuario, produto, $rootScope) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.produto={};
    vm.produtos=[];
    vm.tituloPanel="Produtos";
    vm.quantidaDeRegistrosPorPagina="5";
    vm.pagina = 0;
    vm.filtro = "";
    vm.quantidadeDeRegistros = 0;
    vm.ultimaPagina = false;
    vm.primeiraPagina = false;
    vm.ultimoRegistroDaPagina = 0;    

    vm.filtrar = function(){
        vm.carregarProdutos();
    };

    vm.carregarProdutos=function(zerarPaginacao){
        if (zerarPaginacao){
            vm.pagina = 0;
        }
        produto.getProdutoPaginado(vm.pagina, parseInt(vm.quantidaDeRegistrosPorPagina), vm.filtro ).then(function (retorno) {
            vm.produtos = retorno.conteudo;
            vm.quantidadeDeRegistros = retorno.quantidadeDeRegistros;
            vm.ultimaPagina = retorno.ultimaPagina;
            vm.primeiraPagina = retorno.primeiraPagina;
            vm.ultimoRegistroDaPagina = vm.pagina * vm.quantidadeDeRegistros + parseInt(vm.quantidaDeRegistrosPorPagina);
            if (vm.ultimoRegistroDaPagina > vm.quantidadeDeRegistros) {
                vm.ultimoRegistroDaPagina = vm.quantidadeDeRegistros;
            }
        });
    };


    vm.carregarProdutos(); // this method that a need to call in another controller.

});
```

my other controller

```
app.controller("cadastroProdutoController", function ($http, $location, $q,usuario, produto) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.produto={};
    vm.salvarProduto = function(){
        produto.salvar(vm.produto).then(function (retorno) {
//here i need to put that function
        });

    };

});
```

look that my html

```
<div ng-controller="listaProdutoController as vm">
    <div class="mr-4 ml-4">
        <div class="p-lg-5"></div>
        <div class="card ">
            <div class="card-header">
                {{vm.tituloPanel}}
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group row col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <input type="text" ng-model="vm.filtro" ng-keyup="vm.filtrar($event)" placeholder="Buscar" class="form-control mt-2 form-control-sm">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                            <div class="float-right">
                                <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalCadastroProduto" class="btn btn-blue-grey btn-sm">Adicionar</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group row col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-1">
                            <button type="button" ng-click="vm.proximaPagina()" class="btn btn-blue-grey btn-sm"> ></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mt-2 form-group col-md-1">
                            <select ng-change="vm.carregarProdutos(true)" ng-model="vm.quantidaDeRegistrosPorPagina" class="form-control-sm">
                                <option value="5">5</option>
                                <option value="10">10</option>
                                <option value="15">15</option>
                                <option value="20">20</option>
                                <option value="30">30</option>
                                <option value="40">40</option>
                                <option value="50">50</option>
                                <option value="100">100</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-1">
                            <button type="button" ng-click="vm.paginaAnterior()" class="btn btn-blue-grey btn-sm"> <</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <table class="table table-hover table-sm table-bordered " id="tableProduto" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="th-sm">Id</th>
                        <th class="th-sm">Descrição</th>
                        <th class="th-sm">Observação</th>
                        <th class="th-sm">Opções</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody ng-repeat="pro in vm.produtos">
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{pro.idProduto}}</td>
                        <td>{{pro.descricao}}</td>
                        <td>{{pro.observacao}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <button class="btn btn-blue-grey btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"></button>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                <a class="dropdown-item">Alterar</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" ng-click="vm.excluir(pro)">Excluir</a>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i include the modal with ng-include

```
<div class="modal fade" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" id="modalCadastroProduto" role="dialog">
    <div ng-include src="'./module/cadastroProdutoComponent/cadastroProduto.html'"></div>
</div>
```

and the modal

```
<div ng-controller="cadastroProdutoController as vm">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-top" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                Cadastro de Produto
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form novalidate name="formProduto" role="form">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group row col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                <input type="number" ng-model="vm.produto.idProduto" disabled placeholder="Id" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-9">
                                <input type="text" ng-model="vm.produto.descricao" maxlength="60" placeholder="Descrição" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                <textarea placeholder="Observação" ng-model="vm.produto.observacao" maxlength="250" class="form-control form-control-sm" rows="2"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
                <button data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="vm.salvarProduto()" class="btn btn-blue-grey btn-sm mt-1">Salvar</button>
                <button class="btn btn-blue-grey btn-sm mt-1">Salvar e adicionar novo registro</button>
                <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-blue-grey btn-sm mt-1">Cancelar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `then` method on the `result` of your modal instance:

```
$uibModal.open({
  controller : 'cadastroProdotoController'
}).result.then(() => {
  vm.carregarProdutos();
});
```

If you want to pass data from modal to the initial controller. inside the modal controller you need to close the instance with:

```
 $uibModalInstance.close(data); 
 // where `data` is what you want to pass
```

and to change the above to

```
...
}).result.then(data => {
   // use the returned data
})
```

For convenience, you can place the modal instance in vm:

```
vm.modal = $uibModal.open({/*params here*/});
vm.modal.result.then(data => {/*use data from modal*/})
```